# Can you make a http request using for example nc or wget without curl? (Busybox)

Tags: curl, httprequest, netcat, busybox

I'm currently using a busybox in a Kubernetes Pod and would like to let this Container (busybox) run a http delete request like this:

```
while true; do curl -X DELETE https://blabla.com/api/v1/messages; sleep 604800; done
```

Since curl doesn't work (not available in the image) but nc and wget would work, is there a good way to use them for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wget:

```
 wget --method=DELETE https://blabla.com/api/v1/messages
```

To get result in stdout, like in curl

```
wget -q -O - --method=DELETE http://localhost:8080
```